# what's the difference between getInt() and new Integer(getString())?

Tags: java, jdbc

Assumed that `rs` is a ResultSet obtained from execution of a PreparedStatement or Statement object.
I intended to use `Integer data = rs.getInt(1)` to extract an integer value out of the ResultSet, but my boss asked me to use `Integer data = new Integer(rs.getString(1))` or `Integer data = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(1))` instead.
I just don't understand why. Can anyone tell me what's the benefit of using `getString` instead of `getInt`?

Comment: I suggest to ask your boss :) In general no benefit, but maybe you save int values in database as a strings, so you need to cast them manually.

Comment: Ask your boss to motivate why. Not all RDBMS will take the approach you've mentioned. Some may just return an `int` from the `getInt()` call straight from the database `NUMERIC` type data type. It all depends on the implementation of `ResultSet` by the relevant RDBMS vendors. The best way is to use `ResultSetMetaData` to get the correct data type mapping and call the respective getter method.

Comment: Depends on Database column type.

Comment: The column has a string in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResultSet.getString()` will return a `String` object and `ResultSet.getInt()` returns an `int` value.

`ResultSet.getString()` will work in all cases because all objects can be converted to `String` with `Object.toString()`. `ResultSet.getInt()` will only work if the underlying SQL datatype is a number and it fits into an `int`.

So the `ResultSet.getString()` is more flexible but is obviously less effective if the number is already an integer. Plus it is less likely that anyone would store a number as a string in the database (which would require this conversion).

`null` values are not really a concern because the javadoc of [`ResultSet.getInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-) states that the value `0` is returned if the data is SQL NULL (altough this may not be what you want). And `new Integer(rs.getString(1))` would throw a `NumberFormatException`!

Comment: To check for `NULL` values when using `getInt()` there is `ResultSet.wasNull()`

Comment: Thanks icza, perhaps my boss do want to check a NumberFormatException when the value is null in the underlying database.

Comment: If you look at appendix B of the JDBC 4.2 specification, then `getString` is not supposed to be supported for all datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The field probably may contain SQL NULL so you want java Integer to hold a java null. With the primitive type `int` this is not possible.

You can check the column definition; I expect there is no `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: To check for NULL values for primitive types there is `ResultSet.wasNull()`

Answer (score 0):

In case of Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(1)) you can check NumberFormatException and proceed it as data=null for example. In case of rs.getInt(1) you will receive correct integer "0" value instead of any null marker - so you will not understand that it is empty field and can't write any logic for a null case, which may need different processing - exception or any default value or another "if" clause, etc.